# Automating Google spreadsheet to transfer new info

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking to setup a production line with Google Spreadsheets.

Here's how I intend it to work:

Our Sales Rep John has a spreadsheet specific to him only. He takes in sales leads, and inputs the data into his spreadsheet, which has a field in each row that says if they are ready to go to the next step. If that field is populated with a yes or no, it will take that entire row and transfer the data to another spreadsheet.

From what I've found, I can link specific cells to one another, but I don't know how to link only new information. My goal is to have the row removed from the first spreadsheet and added to the second one for Sales Employee 2 to handle.